# When using default rwd theme why is there nothing inside my language switcher?

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme

I have installed the theme and all I get is a blue line? Where is the text/language switcher?

[image]

Comment: Have you multiple store view?

Comment: I only have a uk site atm but I still want the bar so I can put writing in it etc and maybe account links

Comment: What you want to add and where?

Answer (score 1):

To a switch displayed, you should do at least 2 store view for the current web site. It can do in admin in System > Manage Stores.

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial to create multiple store

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-set-up-and-manage-multiple-stores.html#gref

By default there will be 1 store inside 1 website in Magento.

From admin you need to create new stores, then store switcher will come in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

The languages switcher does not appear unless you have 2 store under the current website you are viewing.
Since you have only one store view for each website this does not appear.
If you want to display for single store then copy `languages.phtml` from

> app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\switch

to

> app\design\frontend\themepackage\yourtheme\template\page\switch

And find `<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>`  and `<?php endif; ?>` just comment these two line .
Now you are able to see the languages switcher.

**Note** : I Have not tested this code but i hope it will work.